# Why does NPM install so many packages?

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

When deploying Node and NPM on Ubuntu 20.04 I noticed that when you run `sudo apt install npm` it details a massive number of dependencies that it want's to install with it. Why is this? Surely it doesn't require all these packages to run the package manager?

Comment: JavaScript is not known for being light. Is this a serious question? You are asking if dependencies are really dependencies.

Comment: "Why is this?" is asking for opinions. You need to ask the creator of npm.

Comment: @Rinzwind If I was looking for an opinion it would have been "What is your opinion" smh. Nmath, I understand that JS has a lot of dependencies but at the time of writing that I didn't realise NPM itself was written in JS, so it makes sense now that it has so many dependencies.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who had this question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reduce the number of installed packages by providing `--no-install-recommends`:

```
sudo apt-get install npm --no-install-recommends
```

---

Comparison for minimal 20.04 LTS system:

- `sudo apt-get install npm`

  > 0 upgraded, 516 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
- `sudo apt-get install npm --no-install-recommends`

  > 0 upgraded, 313 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: This does not answer the "why is this" :-)

Comment: The big recommanded pkgs comes from "build-essential". 
Cf `apt install -s -o Debug::pkgDepCache::AutoInstall=true npm 2>&1 | grep Recommends`

Comment: Nowadays on raspbian bases on Debian 10 Buster form npm version `5.8.0+ds6-4+deb10u2` ... `sudo apt install npm` = 247 deps and `sudo apt install npm --no-install-recommends` = 246 deps :D So almost no difference.

Comment: Why is this not the default? This brought the install size down from 600MB to 117MB. The Windows installer (the Node install MSI) by comparison is only 25MB.